# Filtering on a comparison of nullable strings

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I am using nHibernate to search for mismatching strings.

The model is this:

- `PlayerGroup` has a field `ExpectedPlaylistKey`
- `Player` has a field `LastReportedPlaylistKey`.
- One `PlayerGroup` has many `Players`.

I want to perform a query to find all players that don't match the group's expected playlist.

My code is as follows:

```
PlayerGroup playerGroupAlias = null;
Player playerAlias = null;

var query = this.Session.QueryOver<Player>(() => playerAlias)
                        .JoinAlias(() => playerAlias.PlayerGroup, () => playerGroupAlias)
                        .Where(
                                () => (playerGroupAlias.ExpectedPlaylistKey != playerAlias.CurrentlyReportedPlaylistKey)
                              );
```

I've examined the generated SQL, and it's using this where clause:

```
WHERE not (playergrou1_.ExpectedPlaylistKey = this_.CurrentlyReportedPlaylistKey)
```

Unfortunately, if one of these values is NULL then this returns false, even if the other value is not null.

How can I fix my nHibernate query so it handles the case if either string is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a working answer.

But, given the simplicity of the problem, this looks like really clumsy code.

```
var query = this.Session.QueryOver<Player>(() => playerAlias)
    .JoinAlias(
        () => playerAlias.PlayerGroup,
        () => playerGroupAlias
    ).Where(
        () => 
            (
                (playerAlias.CurrentlyReportedPlaylistKey == null) 
                    && (playerGroupAlias.ExpectedPlaylistKey != null)
            )
            || (
                (playerAlias.CurrentlyReportedPlaylistKey != null) 
                    && (playerGroupAlias.ExpectedPlaylistKey == null)
            )
            || (
               playerGroupAlias.ExpectedPlaylistKey != playerAlias.CurrentlyReportedPlaylistKey
            )
     );
```

As you can see, I've resorted to a lambda expression consisting of five comparisons as well as five other boolean operations, all to ask the question "*are these two strings different*"?

I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.